# How to disable line breaking when reindent?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-resize-columns="" ui-grid-pinning=""
                     ui-grid-pagination="" ui-grid-selection=""></div>
```

I don't want line breaking when I reindent, I want to keep this code on one line.

I'm using webstorm 11. How to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to `Setting/preferences | Code Style | HTML | Other`

Untick `Keep line breaks`

Set `Wrap attributes` to `Do not wrap`

Also disable the following setting so you get a horizontal scrollbar:

- For all files (default setting for opened file):
  `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Use soft wraps in editor`
- For currently opened file in editor: `Menu | View | Active Editor | Use Soft Wraps`

Comment: Is there a way of disabling specific lines. Most of the time the line breaks work well but when you have a `<textarea>` or something like that, a line break introduces a shed load of spaces.